# Location auto fill showing old name of a country

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, location, profile-edit

When editing my profile and changing the location field, I have accidentally bumped into "**Swaziland**" still being listed as a country - although the official name as far as I can recall has been recently changed to "Eswatini" or something similar .

> [image]

BTW, that triggered another check by me - and indeed the former name `Czech Republic` was indeed changed to `Czechia` on the same list ..

Comment: You're correct, this is a bug, but not on Stack Exchange side, but rather on Google side which didn't update their Maps service which SE is using. I assume SE can contact Google via better channels than us though, so it's good you found and reported it. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks, and regarding your edit, I defiantly was browsing that page and **not** editing my location :-) I am not from that country - it was totally accidental :-)

Comment: Well, the only way to trigger the auto fill is by going to Edit mode of the profile, that's what I mean, not that you were actually going to save it. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard in fact, a second check shows that `eSwatini` is also listed.. so now there are two names for the same place ?

Comment: Heh, that's weird. So maybe they left the old name there on purpose, for those unaware the name changed? Still, something only Google can tell. If only Google had a meta site... ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard ..yep.if only . I would also settle for a simple customer service.. anyhow TODA.

Comment: I'd guess the old name is still there so stuff dosen't break on what's probably a simple list

Answer (score 2):

While I hear you...I'm not sure what we should do (if anything) here. It's a Google maps decision and they support both. For example, "eSwatini" is in the list as well, and [Google aliases it to Swaziland](https://www.google.com/maps/search/eSwatini/).

I guess, look at it from the point of view: what if "Swaziland" just went missing? What if all traces of the old name disappeared? That'd be pretty confusing too.

Since you can choose either and elect to update your location to the new name if you wish, I'm going to tag this as [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). I think it's behaving in the only way that's going to suit everyone...and honestly, even if it didn't, there's not much we can do here short of re-creating Google's map and geolocation service.